# Access secured windows folder with java on a linux server

Tags: linux, active-directory, java, mount, user-management

We're trying to mount a secured windows share on a linux server, but until now we're unable to do so. This is the setup we're having:

- A linux server that runs a java application
- A windows share that only allows members of a certain security group for read/write access
- The java application should be able to write files to the windows share
- I am told, as I'm a total Linux newbie, that we should mount that folder
- When we execute the mount command, we're getting "29353: session setup failed: ERRDOS - ERRnoaccess (Access denied.)"
- This probably means that the linux user is not authorized to access the shared folder. This makes sense as a linux user isn't an AD user.

So the real question here is, what should we do so that we can access a secured shared windows folder in a java application run by a linux user? Is the mount a correct solution or do we need another approach. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to mount a CIFS share and you need to do so with a Windows username and password that has access:

```
mkdir /mnt/cifs

mount -t cifs //server-name/share-name /mnt/cifs -o username=shareuser,password=sharepassword,domain=nixcraft
```

Example Source: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-mount-cifs-windows-share/

Comment: You can also do the domain inside the username field `-o username=nixcraft\\shareuser,password=sharepassword`

Comment: As we're using a (legacy, old) linux server, we're only able to mount with - t smbfs. Works like charm! Thanks